# Trying to create something like enumerate inside \paragraph environment

Tags: enumerate, paragraphs

I am working on a report in LaTeX which has a lot of sections and subsections in the table of contents. I have created this all fine, however I have each of my subsubsubsections (used as `\paragraph` in the code) displayed as:

3.2.1.1 My paragraph title: FEP 1

where the number increases by one for each new paragraph. My code to show this is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{My paragraph title: FEP 1}
        \begin{description}[style=multiline,leftmargin=3cm,font=\normalfont]
        \item[X]
        \item[Y] 
        \item[Z] 
        \end{description}

\paragraph{My paragraph title: FEP 2}
        \begin{description}[style=multiline,leftmargin=3cm,font=\normalfont]
        \item[X]
        \item[Y] 
        \item[Z] 
        \end{description}
...
\end{document}
```

However, I have about 60 of these FEP titles but I am constantly changing the report so this number varies as I might delete or add or re-order some which means I have to keep going through the document to re-order these FEP numbers to ensure it reads 1-60 (or how ever many I have). I need to have each of these paragraph titles labelled like this and I cannot use the paragraph number (e.g. 3.2.1.1) for various reasons. Is there any way to write within each of my title paragraphs, code which will automatically label the FEP number correctly and in sequential order. It is like enumerating within the \paragraph{} but that didn't work when I tried it, probably for many obvious reasons! Let me know if this is unclear, finding it hard to explain!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, since not all paragraphs are necessarily FEP-paragraphs, I create a special `\fepparagraph` that steps the `fep` counter, and then invokes `\paragraph` with an FEP identifier suffixed to it.

EDITED to leave vertical mode (Thanks, Ulrike), to properly catch the exceptional case when no text follows a `\fepparagraph` invocation.

Also, I set `tocdepth` to 4 just to confirm that it worked properly inside of the table of contents.  This is not necessary to the actual solution.

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcounter{fep}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\newcommand\fepparagraph[1]{\stepcounter{fep}\paragraph{#1: FEP \thefep}\leavevmode}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\fepparagraph{My paragraph title} 
blah

\fepparagraph{My paragraph title}
blah

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow perfect thank you so much! Exactly what i wanted!

Comment: @Olivia Welcome to the site.  If it is exactly what you wanted, the standard operating procedure is to click the check mark to the left of my answer to "accept" it.  This will tell other readers, if more than one answer is provided, that this answer best addresses your question.  Once you have enough reputation, you will also be able to click the up arrows next to any question or answer (other than your own) to signify that you found the question/answer useful.

Comment: Done! Although, it is now taking ages to run...I guess that's because it is counting through each one and I have about 60 paragraphs...anyway to make it quicker?!

Comment: @Olivia I set the `tocdepth` so that paragraphs appear in your table of contents (they normally would not).  That could account for a lot of computation if you have a lot of paragraphs.  If you don't need them in your toc, you could comment/remove the `tocdepth` line.  Also, it *may* compile faster on subsequent compiles, though I don't guarantee it.

Comment: Better add a \leavevmode, for the case that there is no text behind such a paragraph. And counting 60 paragraphs shouldn't make the compilation slower. There is some other problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks so much for catching that.  Also, the OP didn't say they only had 60 paragraphs, just that they had 60 FEP paragraphs.  They might have hundreds of paragraphs...

Comment: What does a \leavevmode do? Seems to compile fine now after removing the tocdepth line and my paragraphs still appear in my TOC! :)

Comment: @Olivia remove the "blah" after the paragraph and try out what happens with the FEP numbers to see why \leavevmode is useful.

Comment: Remove the adjunct `.toc` file and recompile.  If you are indeed using the `article` class, that should remove them from the toc.  If you are using a document class that includes paragraphs by default, and you don't want them, you can override the default with `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` (sections=depth 1, subsections = depth 2, subsubsections = depth 3, paragraphs = depth 4)

Comment: @Olivia TeX operates in both vertical (page building) and horizontal (paragraph building) modes.  Certain things happen and are reset when entering/leaving a mode.  `\paragraph` headers are constructed in vertical mode, whereas ordinary text forces one into horizontal mode to build a paragraph from it.  When you have two successive `\fepparagraph` invocations without intervening text, one remains in vertical mode the whole time, and the proper resets are not done to step the `fep` counter.  Thus the `\leavevmode` forces an exit from vertical mode.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Ooohh I already had a \setcounter{tocdepth}{4} already that I must've included at another time in a different point in my document which might have been why it wouldn't compile properly before, but it's all just what i want now! Out of interest, is article class a good choice for writing a huge report? (I will be writing my PhD thesis using it!) or is that a bad idea? No idea why I started with it in the first place...! Think I liked the format!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Gotcha, I can see why it's needed now, thanks!

Comment: @Olivia The `article` class is the most used LaTeX class, and is perfectly suitable for thesis work, though some universities have developed their own document classes to use for theses.  It is also easier to get help (from sites like this) for questions involving the `article` class than some specialty class.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Ah perfect, I'll stick to article then, unless Exeter forces me to change! Thanks very much!